# How to upload HTTP API to AWS S3 bucket in JSON File format using Python?

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I can upload my HTTP API to the S3 bucket, but without any file format assigned to it. How could I upload it as a JSON file?

```
import json
import requests
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='***', aws_secret_access_key='***')

covid_text = requests.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents')

data = covid_text.json()

s3.put_object(Body=json.dumps(data), Bucket='my_bucket', Key='httpsGETdisease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code I am using internally for uploading files (generally JSON) to S3. The `self.client` is a cached property which is equivalent to `boto3.client('s3')` in your code above; only I have cached it for reusability, as it's a bit faster when making multiple requests to same bucket, like to read a uploaded file and then re-upload it.

```py
    def upload(self, file_name, bucket, key=None, content_type='application/json'):
        """upload a file (usually a JSON file) to S3"""
        self.client.upload_file(
            file_name, bucket, key or file_name, {'ContentType': content_type})
```

A similar snippet of code when I'm downloading a file from S3 (generally a JSON file). Here we simply check the content type of the object, and if it's JSON then we load it and return the data as a Python `list` or `dict` type. Else, we just return the object data as plaintext.

```py
        content_type = res.get('ContentType', 'application/json')

        data = res['Body'].read().decode(encoding)
        if content_type.endswith('json'):
            return json.loads(data)

        return data
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I do not have a file. I only have the API URL that I provided.

Comment: Ah, I might have missed that. I guess you could continue using `put_object` as you were, and there might be a `content_type` argument (I would refer to the boto3 docs on S3 for clarification)

Comment: Referring to the docs on `put_object` request below, and I see `Body=b'bytes'|file`, so it's expecting Body to be of bytes. You could do try with `covid_text.content` to get the bytes content, and then pass it as the `Body` param? maybe that would work.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

Comment: Additionally I see a `ContentType` argument, so that's probably what you want to use to mark the file as containing JSON content. Since this is an API response, you could use the same header from the response object `covid_text` itself.

Comment: My code works this way: `import json
import requests
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='***',
                  aws_secret_access_key='***')

covid_text = requests.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents')

data = covid_text.json()

s3.put_object(Body=json.dumps(data), Bucket='my_bucket', Key='httpsGETdisease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents', ContentType='application/json')`